# goroutine in loop for map doesn't captured or append value

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine, worker

I have a case where I read an excel file with a third-party package, I need goroutine to do some logic read and insert them into the database during looping,

here is what I tried

```
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var mapMutex sync.RWMutex
    for _, sheet := range originFile.Sheets {
        for _, row := range sheet.Rows {
            
            item := map[string]interface{}{}

            for cellIdx, cell := range row.Cells {
                wg.Add(1)
                cell := cell
                cellIdx := cellIdx

                go func() {
                    defer wg.Done()
                    index := fmt.Sprintf("%v", sheet.Rows[0].Cells[cellIdx])
                    logrus.Info(item[index]) //  i got <nil> here
                    mapMutex.Lock()
                    item[index] = cell
                    mapMutex.Unlock()
                }()

            }
            // i want `item` here to do something again for my function
            logrus.Info(item) // i got map[] here (empty)
        }
    }

    wg.Wait()
```

why I do that because the data, more than >10.000 so I need to use that to read and insert into the database ( there are some logic also )

does anyone here had that issue before? how did u solved that ??

Comment: There is a race: logrus.Info line reads `item` without mapMutex lock. Even after you fix it, there is no guarantee that `item` will not be empty, because it is being filled asynchronously.

Comment: did u mean that I need to not use `mapMutex` for this case?  @BurakSerdar

Comment: You need to use it when you are logging it as well.

Comment: is that mean what i do above is already ok? and just need to add `mapMutex` between it to log?? @BurakSerdar

Comment: It will not log correctly even if you add mutex. There is no guarantee that goroutines will run and fill `item` before you log. Move the logging to after `wg.Wait`. You can remove the mutexes as well if you do that.

Comment: but i want to do something on `item` in looping `sheet.Rows`, if logging does not work, it will not work also to do some logic inside there? @BurakSerdar

Comment: There is no guarantee on when the goroutines will be scheduled. If you need to do work using `item` after the inner loop, consider doing that work in a separate goroutine that is tied to the worker goroutines with a channel, so they can receive work as completed.

Answer (score 0):

I would reconsider if you need a go routine at all there. If not, everything will be easier. But if you have a strong requirement and resources for the goroutines to make sense, you need to do two things, but first let me explain why!

Basically your most inner for loop is iterating over `row.Cells` as fast as the CPU and drive allows it, spawns a goroutine and iterates over next one and so on. The `item` is a local variable which is known only in the scope of the for loop.

So you need to:

- first prepare the map with make: `item := make(map[string]interface{})`
- then pass it as an argument to the goroutine function with other values needed:

```
go func(i map[string]interface{}, c string, cIdx int) {
    ...
}(item, cell, cellIdx)
```

and also like someone commented: you need a mutex even when reading from the map when logging.